# Keeping track of multiple requestCodes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm creating an app which copies the functionality of the default alarm app. I'm storing all of the user's *entries* (alarms) in a Room database (to display all of my alarms in a *RecyclerView*). Whenever I store an entry, I set an alarm using the *AlarmManager*.

**How do I make sure that the user can edit an alarm which is already set?**

As I understand, I need to create an identical *PendingIntent* (which includes also the same *requestCode* and then use the *cancel* method).
I want to use the *rowIds* from the DB as *requestCodes* for the alarm.

How do I make sure that when the user modifies an alarm I have access to the corresponding *rowId*?

Of course, I can make DB queries to get back the *rowId* based on the other properties which I save in the *TextViews* from the *RecyclerView* (title, description, date), but is there a better way?
Should I also save the *rowId* in an invisible *TextView* (for easy access to the data)?

The answer to a somewhat similar question posted here was to set an alarm only when a previously set alarm fires. I don't think this is a solution since I can have multiple alarms which need to be triggered at the same time.

Also, please help if you know a better method.

Comment: Are you using auto generated ids within your Room database? If you have those, those would be a good value to use for the request code. I may add an offset though. Such as ( 1000 + id ).

Comment: Yes, I use automatically generated ids. This way, I avoid making any blunders with generating ids on the spot.